# Форматирование даты по оси Х в matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Как сделать формат даты по оси абсцисс в виде Янв 2020 (или Jan 2020)?

Данные:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_excel('https://github.com/At7sharp/FSK/blob/main/Metal_AT3_result.xlsx?raw=true')
df['file_date'] = df['file_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.sort_values('file_date')
```

Отрисовка графиков:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('default')

x = df.loc[:, 'file_date'].values.tolist()
y1 = df.loc[:, 'vfd_power_mean'].values.tolist()
y2 = df.loc[:, 'shaot_power_mean'].values.tolist()
y3 = df.loc[:, 'power_saving_mean'].values.tolist()
y4 = df.loc[:, 'air_temp'].values.tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(16,16), dpi= 60)
ax[2].set(title='Temp')
ax[0].fill_between(x, 0, y2, label='ШАОТ', alpha=1)
ax[0].fill_between(x, 0, y1, label='ЧРП', alpha=1)
ax[1].fill_between(x, 0, y3, label='profit')
ax[2].plot(x, y4, label = 'Temp')

ax[0].legend(loc='upper left')
ax[1].legend(loc='upper left')
ax[2].legend(loc='upper left')

# Найстройка осей
#ax.set_xlim([-10, 10])
ax[0].set_ylim([0, 300]) # Границы по оси У
ax[1].set_ylim([0, 300])
ax[2].set_ylim([-15, 30])
#ax[0].set_xlabel('Даты')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Мощность, кВт')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Мощность, кВт')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Температура, °C')

# Настройка сетки
#ax[2].grid(which='major', color = 'k')
#ax[2].grid(which='minor', color = 'grey')
ax[0].grid()
ax[1].grid()
ax[2].grid()

# Названия графиков
ax[0].set(title='Потребление электроэнергии ЧРП и ШАОТ')
ax[1].set(title='Экономия электроэнергии')
ax[2].set(title='Температура воздуха')

#  Устанавливаем интервал основных делений:
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(58))
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(58))
ax[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(58))
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))

# Установка расстояния между таблицами
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0.35)

# Поля графиков (почему-то только для последнего)
#plt.margins(x=0,y=0)

plt.show()
```

В результате получается пока так:

[image: graph]

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте больше использовать [средства визуализации Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('https://github.com/At7sharp/FSK/blob/main/Metal_AT3_result.xlsx?raw=true')

cols_map = dict(
    file_date="Дата", 
    air_temp="Temp", 
    shaot_power_mean="ШАОТ", 
    vfd_power_mean="ЧРП", 
    power_saving_mean="profit"
)
t = df.rename(columns=cols_map).set_index("Дата").rename_axis(None)

fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(12,16), dpi= 60)
ax0.set_ylim([0, 300]) # Границы по оси У
ax1.set_ylim([0, 300])
ax2.set_ylim([-15, 30])

t["Temp"].plot(ax=ax2, title="Температура воздуха", ylabel="Температура, °C", legend=True)
t[["ШАОТ", "ЧРП"]].plot.area(
    ax=ax0,
    stacked=False,
    alpha=1,
    title="Потребление электроэнергии ЧРП и ШАОТ",
    ylabel="Мощность, кВт",
    legend=True)
t["profit"].plot.area(
    ax=ax1,
    stacked=False,
    alpha=1,
    title="Экономия электроэнергии",
    ylabel="Мощность, кВт",
    legend=True)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сами выставляете формат даты, который вам не нужен.
сделайте сначала сортировку значений по дате, а потом отформатируйте ее:

```
df = df.sort_values('file_date')
df['file_date'] = df['file_date'].dt.strftime('%d %b %Y')
```

Формат метода strftime описан [здесь](https://strftime.org/)

На выходе получите колонку `file_date` в таком виде.

```
       file_date
0    24 Dec 2018
1    25 Dec 2018
2    26 Dec 2018
3    27 Dec 2018
4    28 Dec 2018
..           ...
577  26 Apr 2021
578  27 Apr 2021
579  28 Apr 2021
580  29 Apr 2021
581  30 Apr 2021
```

Ну и, соответственно,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]